# Хранит ли адрес сама переменная в с++?

Tags: c++

Не могу понять один аспект работы с переменными в c++.
Допустим мы объявили int a, система выделила под нее 4 байта памяти. Но ведь все 4 байта выделяются под саму переменную, а мы можем воспользоваться и ее адресом (&a). Соответственно сам адрес где то храниться, не могу понять где)

Comment: Для простоты — считайте, что при работе он вычисляется... Хранится он во внутренней таблице при *компиляции*.

Comment: Переменная может физически храниться в регистре (если так решит сделать компилятор), тогда у нее вообще не будет адреса как такового. Если же где-то понадобится ее адрес (указатель на переменную), то компилятор скорее всего разместит переменную в памяти.

Comment: Ну, когда система выделяет эти 4 байта под конкретную переменную, она "помнит", где именно она их выделила. Таким образом, можно сказать, что адрес - косвенно - хранится в коде программы